# OpenCV matchTemplate - matching methods

Tags: java, c++, opencv, ocr, pattern-recognition

I am trying to use the opencv matchTemplate to recognize a number in a picture.

What i am trying to do is to find out what number is on a lottery ball, The ball will always be in the same place in the picture but the angle of which you can see the number will change.

I am trying to autodetect the number on the ball using matchTemplate and a threshold.

My problem Is that it doesnt always give me the currect number for my threshold.

I saw the matchTemplate has several matching methods, I just used TM_SQDIFF.

What is the difference between each of the matching methods? I cant see any detailed explanation on that.

ty.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the difference between the matching methods in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html). There's an example with pictures [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html#template-matching).

Comment: I saw both, but what does it really tell you? which will be better to recognize a number for instance?

Comment: Template matching is sensitive to the rotation, so unless you have a lot of templates with different rotations, non of them. If you have multiple templates, all of them could work.